# Reading each line and writing to the end of it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and if I am asking a very simple question, please excuse.

I am trying to read each line from a text file and predict the sentiment of each line and write the output to the end of the text file. For  that I am trying to append data to the end of the line.

My text file looks like below :

```
I am awesome.
I am terrible.
I am bad.
```

What I am trying to achieve is below :

```
I am awesome. - Positive
I am terrible. - Negative
I am bad. - Negative
```

When I run the code, the file is being saved as empty. Please help.

My code is as below :

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import names


def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])


positive_vocab = ['awesome', 'outstanding', 'fantastic', 'terrific', 'good', 'nice', 'great', ':)']
negative_vocab = ['bad', 'terrible', 'useless', 'hate', ':(']

positive_features = [(word_feats(pos), 'pos') for pos in positive_vocab]
negative_features = [(word_feats(neg), 'neg') for neg in negative_vocab]

train_set = negative_features + positive_features

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

# Predict
neg = 0
pos = 0

f = open("test.txt", "r")
for sentence in f.readlines():
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        classResult = classifier.classify(word_feats(word))
        if classResult == 'neg':
            f.write(' negative')
        if classResult == 'pos':
            f.write(' positive')

f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write to a file that is open in 'r' mode - that mode is for reading.

My suggestion is to open the file for reading, and open a second file and write out to that. So something like:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
out_file = open("output.txt", "w")
for sentence in f.readlines():
    orig = sentence
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        classResult = classifier.classify(word_feats(word))
        if classResult == 'neg':
            out_file.write(orig + ' negative')
        if classResult == 'pos':
            out_file.write(orig + ' positive')

f.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: The file could also be read to a variable, then closed, and overwritten.

Comment: True! That runs into possible memory issues on large files, but it could be easier in a lot of cases.

Answer (score -3):

You are opening the file in read mode. You would need to open the file in write.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
```